# Request to change color of silver badge : Make it more bright and shiny

Tags: feature-request, badges

The current color of silver badge looks more like light grey and doesn't have the desired shine. I believe it should be more lightening/flashy silver color. We all know silver badge has more value than bronze but in appearance somehow that differentiation doesn't feel obvious at once. It should actually look like that it has more value than bronze from its look and feel as well.

Have a look at the olympic medals:

[image]

Another one:

[image]

Have a look at the color of badges on SO where gold and bronze look very apt. Gold is quite bright (suggesting Rank 1) and bronze is fairly dull (suggesting Rank 3).

[image]

This might look like a cosmetic change but of course this certainly gives a sense of achievement so I feel silver badge should be relatively more brighter/shining.

Comment: Silver *is* light grey.

Comment: Silver isn't a color and there's no way to give it "shine". If you look at the vector illustrated medals, the shine is just implied by the use of gradients.

Comment: Are you just asking for a lighter gray?

Comment: @Jefromi May be some bright lining on the circumference of the badge which can make it look apart. Not sure if choosing a lighter gray will be of real help or not? Some UX/UI expert can comment better on this front.

Answer (score 12):

Those medals you show are very large and detailed vector images. If you make those medals as small as the current badge icons you won't see anything of the details you shown:

[image]

[image]

In the end, silver is just another grey, so if you make it lighter it will look more white, which doesn't make it more shinier. If you want to achieve that effect, you need to add some shadow and lighting, but as said, those have virtually no effect on such a small image.

Those icons are good as they are.

Comment: Once Apple announces their zillion-DPI retina eye inplant next week your argument of the medals being too small will be futile...

Comment: No, although these are small images, they are not so small that it couldn't be done. Although probably a programmer can't do it, it requires a designer.

Comment: I doubt that if you put them on the black background they have now, you will see anything of that gradient.